# Kohana 3, serve image stored in a database

Tags: kohana, kohana-3

I had this working on kohana 2, but in kohana 3 it doesn't.

To serve an image stored as BLOB in a database, I did the following:

1- A controller to which I request what image do I want. I connects to the database, using a model of course, and serve the image using a view.

```
$prod = ORM::factory('product',$idx);
$img = new View('image');
$img->pic = $prod->getImage();
```

2-The model has a little trick to get this working:

```
public function getImage() 
  {
    return imagecreatefromstring($this->image);
  }
```

image is the blob column where I store the picture I want to serve.

3- In the view:
I set the content-type header and then serve the image

```
header('content-type: image/png; charset=UTF-8');
imagepng($pic);
```

This worked in Kohana 2, but in KO3 it doesn't,

I'm trying to use $response->send_file(), but I'm getting lost

Comment: show your controller code please (with a `$response->send_file()` etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should never send headers with header() unless you're hacking the fw. Ko3.1 nicely separates Request from Response and the latter is the one responsible for response headers / everything else (both of them are written pretty much following the [RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt)).

Secondly, there is absolutelly no need for a view file in this case, Response::$_body is what the current response object returns.

Response::send_file() returns the response as download, I suppose that's not what you're trying to accomplish?

So, you need something like this (modify to your own needs):

```
public function action_image($id)
{
    $image = ORM::factory('product', $id);

    if ( ! $image->loaded()) // ... 404 ?

    $this->response
        ->headers('Content-Type','image/png')
        ->body($image->image)
        ->check_cache(NULL, $this->request); // 304 ?
}
```

Comment: btw. I'd recommend you to use the native database functions for this and also saving the etag in db less later overhead (passing it later as the first param for check-cache)

Comment: it went great!, thank you!

I had to return the data from the database as it is, imagecreatefromstring broke the image... don't really sure why (I mean, it worked in KO2). I was in a hurry with this, so, thank you again!